# Can we integrate test results TestNG reports or extent reports to Microsoft teams

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, microsoft-teams

Our tech director wanted test results which are currently in testng reports to be updated in Microsoft teams channel once the tests are run.

We are currently using testng reports to analyze reports after test runs.

Can we integrate Selenium testng results or extent reports to microsoft teams.

Comment: Framework is hybrid page object model with data driven . Test data is from Excel.

Comment: Have you looked at using incoming webhooks? We can point you to the info.

Answer (score 1):

If you are Using Jenkins to schedule the tests, you can use the Post Build Actions > Editable Email Notification in you build job.

- Add Project Recipient List  - In this option you can add any number of email recipients. Refer the image for more details -
  [Project Recipient List in Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufXMM.png)
- If you need to integrate with your Microsoft Teams Channel, you can get the email for that channel by following the below steps:

  - Go to the channel name and click More options  More options button > Get email address.
  - This option needs to be enable by your IT admin.
- Also you  can look at incoming web hooks option in Microsoft Teams [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors-using)
- So, if you have any CI/CD server (like Jenkins) notifying test results, you can integrate any email address in the post build action of the Job.

Comment: @ Tuhin, Thanks . will explore these options we are still not using Jenkins but plan to do so. will update how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Travis CI to send the notifications to your teams channel. Here are the steps.

1. Pick your team and the relevant channel (Ex: Your Team > General)
2. click on the three little dots on the bottom of channel > more apps (screenshot below)

[image]

3. Then select connectors > and pick travis CI> install it.

[image]

4. You have now two options. Now you can easily login in to Travis CI (assuming you have account and configured your TESTNG reports) and make a connection or as mentioned above get the email address and configure it in your build.
5. When ever TESTNG build reports are complete this channel will be notified as an "Adaptive cards".

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is an npm package to publish test results back to either microsoft teams or slack.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-results-reporter

You need to create an incoming-webhook and a simple config file to get started.

If you are using Azure DevOps, add the below command in your pipeline yaml file.

```
- script: npx test-results-reporter publish -c config.json
```