# How to publish test report in YAML file to Teams Notification

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, microsoft-teams, webhooks

I have connected GitLab CI CD with Misrosoft Teams using Incoming Webhook, to display notifications about GitLab project in Microsoft Teams

[image]

I want to include Test Report(or link to report) in Teams Notification, how can I do that?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: here is related thread-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131043/can-we-integrate-test-results-testng-reports-or-extent-reports-to-microsoft-team#:~:text=There%20is%20an%20npm%20package%20to%20publish%20test,the%20below%20command%20in%20your%20pipeline%20yaml%20file.
hope it's helpful.

Comment: check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57050321/how-do-i-post-a-message-to-microsoft-team-from-other-application/65759554#65759554